# Webview check cache and limit download

Tags: android, caching, webview

I am using [loadData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to load html  in webview. Users might enter url's in html. But I 'm planning to ask user to "do you really want to download this content" whenever html is not in cache. I do not know how to check cache in my case. Looks like [webviewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) does not have any suitable method for this?

For example shouldInterceptRequest is fired whether html is in cache or not, and I cannot discern whether html is in cache or not. Any help?